# Pattern Builder to create multiple objects at once (list)

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I would like to create a Builder pattern to create multiple objects at once.
Because with basic builder pattern it can only build one object..

Example of what I did:

```java
package builders;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class UserBuilder {
    private List<User> users;
    private int userCount;

    private UserBuilder() {
    }

    private UserBuilder(int userCount) {
        this.userCount = userCount;
    }

    private UserBuilder(UserBuilder copy) {
        this.users = copy.users;
        this.userCount = copy.userCount;
    }

    public static UserBuilder user() {
        return new UserBuilder();
    }

    public static UserBuilder users(int userCount) {
        return new UserBuilder(userCount);
    }

    public UserBuilder withFirstname(String firstName) {
        return withFirstname((unused) -> firstName);
    }

    public UserBuilder withFirstname(Function<Integer, String> func) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
            users.get(i).setFirstName(func.apply(i));
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        return withLastName((unused) -> lastName);
    }

    public UserBuilder withLastName(Function<Integer, String> func) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
            users.get(i).setLastName(func.apply(i));
        return this;
    }

    public User build() {
        return user.get(0);
    }

    public User build(int index) {
        return user.get(index);
    }

    public List<User> buildAll() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
// Our builder can be use to create single object like basic builder:
User user = UserBuilder.user()
        .withFirstName("toto")
        .withLastName("tata")
        .build();
// OR it can also build 10 users and set parameters thanks to lambdas
List<User> users = UserBuilder.users(10)
        .withFirstName((index) -> "toto" + index)
        .withLastName("tata")
        .buildAll();
// users will have firstName=toto$index and all will have lastName=tata
```

What do you think about this pattern?
This is what I want BUT I must duplicate all my methods (with its lambda version..)
Maybe there is a way to delete 50% of methods by adding an annotation or something like that?

Is there a cleaner version?

Answer (score 0):

The more common approach (also used in e.g. JavaFX) would be to stay with a single object builder but re-use the common fields.
In your example you aren't winning much by having the list allocation in your `Builder`.

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static class UserBuilder {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public UserBuilder firstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(firstName, lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

```
User user = new User.UserBuilder().firstName("toto").lastName("tata").build();

User.UserBuilder commonBuilder = new User.UserBuilder().lastName("tata");
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    users.add(commonBuilder.firstName("toto" + i).build());
}

List<User> users2 = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(index -> commonBuilder.firstName("toto" + index).build()).toList();
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be helpful:

[How difficult can it ever be to build a list of objects in Java and Kotlin using the builder pattern?](https://davidecerbo.medium.com/how-difficult-can-it-ever-be-to-build-a-list-of-objects-in-java-and-kotlin-using-the-builder-fb0d0a8a5ca6)

Part of the code:

> ```
> class ManufacturerListBuilder {
>     
>     private String continent;
>     private final List<Manufacturer> manufacturers = new LinkedList<>();
>
>     public ManufacturerListBuilder withContinent(String continent) {
>         this.continent = continent;
>         return this;
>     }
>
>     ManufacturerListBuilder add(Function<ManufacturerBuilder, ManufacturerBuilder> builderFunction) {
>         
>         ManufacturerBuilder builder = ManufacturerBuilder
>            .apply(new ManufacturerBuilder()
>                         .withContinent(continent))
>            .build();
>
>         this.manufacturers.add(builder);
>         return this;
>     }
>
>     public Collection<UserFilter> getManufacturers() {
>         return this.manufacturers;
>     }
> }
> ```